Saturated ideal of the integral (resp. reduced) projective variety
Let $K$ be a field, $X$ be a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n_K$. Then $X=\text{Proj}\;K[x_0,...,x_n]/I$ for some saturated ideal $I$ (see, for example [Hartshorne, Exercise 2.5.10]).
My question is, if $X$ is integral (resp. redcued), then the ring $K[x_0,...,x_n]/I$ is integral (resp. reduced)?
Any reference or answer would be perfect (Note that our field $K$ doesn't require algebraic closed, so the Charpter one of Hartshonre may not enough).
